# Wrong version of node used when deploying Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite, meteoric

Node.js 0.10.22 was installed using NVM. After installing [meteoric](https://github.com/julien-c/meteoric.sh) and running

```
meteoric deploy
forever logs 0
```

we get the error output from Meteor

```
data:    bundle/main.js:10138 - error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
data:    bundle/main.js:10138 - error: Forever restarting script for 0 time
data:    bundle/main.js:10138 - Meteor requires Node v0.10.21 or later.
data:    bundle/main.js:10138 - error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
data:    bundle/main.js:10138 - error: Forever restarting script for 1 time
data:    bundle/main.js:10138 - Meteor requires Node v0.10.21 or later.
data:    bundle/main.js:10138 - error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

---

```
$ node -v
v0.10.22

$ which node
/root/.nvm/v0.10.22/bin/node
```

**Question:** Seems like theres a problem with forever and NVM? Why is forever/meteor/meteorite saying that Node's version is older than v0.10.21? Any ideas on solving this problem?

Comment: I don't use meteoric, but I had a look at the script and it seems to use Chris Lea's `node.js-legacy` repo which installs node 0.8.x. Meteor, as of 0.6.6, uses node 0.10.x. I'm not sure if this is the problem, but it sure doesn't look right.

Comment: @DavidWeldon I rebuilt the server instance and did everything from scratch again, installing only node 0.10.22 using NVM. Now the problem is that forever/meteor is not finding the correct version of node. Why is forever/meteor using the node version from chris-lea rather than nvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion, it sounds like you have the wrong version of node installed. See the [history.md](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md) file for which version of node you should be running. If you are using the latest version of meteor, it's 0.10.21 as of this writing.

I think the right strategy is to ensure that no other version of node gets installed. If you want to use meteoric I would try the following:

1. Start with a clean server instance.
2. Install the correct version of node for your meteor version.
3. Comment out lines 61 and 64 from [meteoric.sh](https://github.com/julien-c/meteoric.sh/blob/master/meteoric.sh) (the ones which add `node.js-legacy` and install `npm`) Note you may want to remove the `sudo` from the other npm commands depending on how you installed node in step 2.
4. Allow meteoric to do its setup magic.

If all of that works, you should probably file an issue with meteoric to change the way node is installed.